# Google Calendar API gives 403 error during OAuth even though it seems to grant access

Tags: oauth-2.0, elixir, google-oauth, google-calendar-api

My app will publish, edit and delete events on users' Google Calendars. I am configuring OAuth to make this happen. The idea is that upon signup, the user will be able to go into their settings and give consent to connect my app to their Google Calendar. I will then be able to store the oauth token and refresh token in the database and use them to when I create/edit/delete events on the user's calendar.

Anyway, the issue is that I pick my account:

[image: Choosing account]

I then provide consent by clicking "Allow":

[image: Allowing access]

Here is where it gets weird: behind the scenes, the Google Calendar API reports a 403 Forbidden error.

```
%Ueberauth.Failure{errors: [%Ueberauth.Failure.Error{message: 403,
message_key: "OAuth2"}], provider: :google,
strategy: Ueberauth.Strategy.Google}
```

My `ueberauth` config:

```
config :ueberauth, Ueberauth,
  providers: [
    google: {Ueberauth.Strategy.Google, [default_scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar", approval_prompt: "force", access_type: "offline"]}
]
```

The request I'm making:

```
def callback(%{assigns: %{ueberauth_failure: fail}} = conn, _params) do
  IO.inspect fail
  conn
  |> put_flash(:error, "Failed to authenticate.")
  |> redirect(to: "/")
end

def callback(%{assigns: %{ueberauth_auth: auth}} = conn, _params) do
  IO.inspect auth
  conn
  |> put_flash(:success, "Connected to Google.")
  |> redirect(to: "/")
end
```

The first `callback` function is the one that matches (since it fails).

*However*, when I go to my Google account, I can see that the app has been granted permission:

[image: Access granted]

I am providing the correct client_id and client_secret. In addition, I have created a service account in the Google API Console and shared my calendar with that account:

[image: Calendar sharing settings]

What else do I need to do?

**Edit:** Some more info - I am able to grant access to all other Google modules via my code (which is boilerplate [Ueberauth_Google](https://github.com/ueberauth/ueberauth_google)). For example, if I make the request with email as the scope, it works and I get the auth_token from Google. Only Google Calendar gives 403, which leads me to believe there is something specific about it that is causing it.

**Edit 2:** I looked at the [error handling section of the Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/errors), and none of the 403 errors listed there apply to me:

- 403: Daily Limit Exceeded
- 403: User Rate Limit Exceeded
- 403: Rate Limit Exceeded
- 403: Calendar usage limits exceeded

**Edit 3:** I created a brand new Google account and shared its calendar with my Google Service Account. That one gives the same error though.

Comment: Why do you tag the question `elixir` ?

Comment: It looks like he's trying to use Elixir but it also looks like he hasn't done anywhere near enough work to try to isolate the actual problem.  Downvote.

Comment: @Onorio Catenacci: Your comment is absolutely is ridiculous because not only is it not helpful, it is also rude. How do you determine that I "haven't done anywhere near enough work to try to isolate the actual problem"? Please explain specifically what led you to this impression, because it is very wrong.

Comment: Post code that actually demonstrates your issue and I'll retract my comment. Until you can give us a [minimal, complete, and viable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example to reproduce your issue, as far as I'm concerned you haven't done anywhere near enough work to get an answer.

Comment: Posting lots of information is not the same thing as posting the _important_ information.

Comment: Your comments are abrasive and unhelpful. Please stop.

Comment: 403 response code would indicate to me a scope issue. Is it possible that 403 is with regards to write access to the calendar and that the authorization reflected is that of a read access only? It is a far shot, but could you try to set scope to calendar with read only?

Comment: Also, could you try making the oauth requests through `curl`? Check https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749 for the actual requests under the hood.

Comment: @KevinJohnson The `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly` scope gives the same error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally figured it out.

The `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar` scope by itself was not sufficient. Also needed to add `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile` to the scope.